# C++: How to set GUID to NULL instead of GUID_NULL?

Tags: c++, sql, database

I have a database which uses GUIDs instead of, say, an ordinary counter for the ID fields. But I can't seem to put NULL (instead of GUID_NULL) into such fields in DB even though. Yes, the field in the database does take NULL.

Let's say there is a parent-child relationship between two tables. So there is a parent and a child GUID references from one table to another. But the "root" parent does not have any parent and there I would like to be able to put NULL into its ParentUID database field. If I put GUID_NULL there then I will need a corresponding default row in the referenced table which has a GUID-value of GUID_NULL so that the foreign key constraint won't break.

Also, using GUID_NULL with default-rows at referenced tables will give me a resultset back when doing a standard join operation...which is not desirable.

They way it's done in code when inserting values into database is using a CCommand which takes structure that contains the values of the row fields to be inserted. One of these is a GUID type variable.

So it creates an SQL statement string looking like

```
INSERT INTO [tablename] (field1, field2, field3,...) VALUES(?,?,?,...)
```

and then in a loop there is something like:

```
command.field1 = 1;
command.field2 = 2;
command.GUIDField = ?????? //I want to put NULL here instead of GUID_NULL

command.Open(...);
```

I hope it is understandable what I wish to do and what the conditions in code are.
Thankful for help!

UPDATE:
Ok, it was very hard to exaplin correctly, but this is exactly what I want to do http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260900
Just that when I follow that example, it makes no difference...still I get FK constraint violation on insert so I suspect it is trying to insert GUID_NULL instead of NULL. :(

Comment: Which SQL library are you using?  Will using `NULL` (type `void *`) or `nullptr` (type `nullptr_t`) work?

Comment: have you set your table to allow null values? I know I can overlook setting that.

Comment: Thanks for both the replies! 
@BrianCain I am having a bit of trouble testing this now but I shall return öater and try your solution.

To GMasucci : Yes I believe I wrote that in my original post. It is allowing NULL yes.

Comment: @BrianCain Ok, atldbcli.h defines the CCommand with a CAccessor which is initialized with a template taking a struct where one member is a GUID in my case. The SQL string is then loaded into into the command object hr = command.Create(*m_session, strSQL) before calling command.Open();

But I face the same problem when loading values from DB. I can't set the guid varible to null, so I can only fetch GUID_NULL.

I hope this makes any sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link I had in my Update-section does work, my bad: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260900
It is the answer to my problems, perhaps it will help someone else as well! :3

Comment: the link is dead (`Sorry, page not found 404`), but `memset(&myGuidVar, 0, sizeof(myGuidVar));` should do the trick...

Comment: @Top-Master Oh no, I should have copied the contents of the link into my answer perhaps. My bad. I don't remember what the solution was in the link but maybe your solution works. Thanks!